# How to install ros-groovy-rviz on RaspberryPi?

Tags: rviz, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,all!

I installed ROS on RaspberryPi:binary package.

I'd like to use Rviz,and install from debian repository.

I'm using following command.

sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-rviz

But,error occurred.
How to install rviz from debian repository?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70339/how-to-install-ros-groovy-rviz-on-raspberrypi?/) by [taichi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5121/taichi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Only a subset of packages are available for the RaspberryPi and rviz is probably not one of them due to it's large system dependencies and hardware requirements.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [taichi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5121/taichi/) on 2013-10-14**:
Thank you!!